# Email after Form Submit, Problem with Calculations

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've currently got a trigger on form submit to run my code which pulls in the submitted data and emails a summary to the user. I need to perform calculations on the submitted data and provide those results in the summary email. I've been able to hard code this and I have a working script but I want to do the calculations on one of the sheets instead. I've got another sheet setup to pull in the form data and perform the calculations but it seems the problem is that when the form data is submitted, none of the other sheets are updated so if I try to pull calculations from the other sheets it will not include the latest entry.

I've tried getting data from other sheets but I don't think the other sheet calculations are refreshing to include the newly submitted data, or the code is executing before the sheets can refresh, possibly order of operations limitation. The desired goal would be to have a user submit the form, then have all sheets using that data pull it in and complete calculations, then send an email using the newly calculated results. Ideally pulling data from multiple sheets.

I'm thinking the "on form submit" trigger is not appropriate here, instead maybe I need to have an event occur on the sheet or sheets I'm using to calculate that triggers an email. Or does anyone know if there's a way to force all sheets to update and fields to calculate before continuing to execute the code?

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the code you are working on so that we understand what you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I got 100% what you're looking for but you need to know that if it's your function who is opening a Spreadsheet and writing data on it, you can't add any trigger.
Trigger can only run following a "human" action (onOpen, onEdit..)

Comment: The trigger is a standard "on form submit" which executes my function. The function reads data from the last line of the sheet that the form data was written to. The human action in this case is a user submitting a form.

Comment: Do you have an example of what you want to achieve? Because to me it's not really clear then . Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Pl. try importrange in the target sheet/sheets to pull data from the form sheet.

You have to maintain "completed" in a seperate sheet.

If you see a new entry, do the calculation, send mail and update the completed field.